# How can I compare the values in two matrices in R?

Tags: r

I have two matrices containing mass spec data similar to a form of:

```
m1
    [1]  [2]
[1]  Q1   2
[2]  Q2   1

m2
    [1]  [2]
[1]  Q2   3
[2]  P5   1
```

and I first want to compare the elements in the first columns (contains accession codes such as P1) among the matrices and if they are the same, I want to compare the second column (a value associated with that access code 1,2,3 etc.) and compare the values and append to a new matrix (both the value and the accession code) if only the compared values satisfy the condition of m1*2 > 2. I am a new bioinformatician and could really use some help :(. Thank you all!

Comment: Are matrices required? In your case I would recommend to use data.frames.

Comment: To expand on the suggestion to use `data.frame`: A `matrix` in R can only hold one data type. In your example, all values would be converted to character... Also I'd suggest proof reading your question (e.g. there is no value P1)

Answer (score 0):

If I use data frames like these:

```
Col1<-c("Q1","Q2")
Col2<-c(2,1)
m1<-data.frame(Col1,Col2)
> m1
  Col1 Col2
1   Q1    2
2   Q2    1
```

And

```
Col1<-c("Q2","P5")
Col2<-c(3,1)
m2<-data.frame(Col1,Col2)
m2
  Col1 Col2
1   Q2    3
2   P5    1
```

You can use this

```
m1[intersect(which(m1$Col1==intersect(m1$Col1,m2$Col1)), which(m1$Col2*2>2)),]
```

To return the values from m1 which satisfy the condition. Here, it does not return any row because there is no match. But it works, if you change the second condition to m1*2 > 1:

```
> m1[intersect(which(m1$Col1==intersect(m1$Col1,m2$Col1)), which(m1$Col2*2>1)),]
  Col1 Col2
2   Q2    1
```

I believe there might be something shorter or more elegant with `dplyr`, but this is what I have so far. If this is not what you expect, please edit the post with your expected result.

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice, I will share the code once it is finished.

Comment: You don't need to share your final code. If this answer works for you on this example and answers the question you asked here, you can just upvote or accept the answer(s) (see that [post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=To%20accept%20an%20answer%3A,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.). You can upvote several answers, but only accept one. Also: people try to help based on the example you provide. Adjustments may be needed on your side to adapt the solution to your actual data. That's part of the game & on you, we can only provide solutions to your specific question here.